# Can the header note about possible answer elsewhere on this question be removed?

Tags: support, duplicates

See [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/36323/whats-the-purpose-of-time-signature-information-in-a-midi-file/36363#36363). It has been wrongly tagged with a "possible answer elsewhere" header (likely due to the mistaken first comment). Can this be removed please?

Comment: I don't see a "header", just the comment.  Maybe this only appears to you, can you try looking when signed out or in a private browsing session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This header note appears **to the owner of the question only**, when there is a pending vote to mark the question as a duplicate. Unless the question is really closed as a duplicate, nothing is shown to the public.

This is to encourage the question owners to agree that it's a duplicate in cases where they agree; this speeds up the "duplication" process and helps clean the queues.

If you don't agree with the duplicate, the best thing is to leave a comment explaining why it's not a duplicate.